# x64 Windows reports 32GB RAM usable out of 64GB RAM installed - why?

Tags: memory, 32bit-64bit, 64-bit

I've got a server with 64GB RAM installed (reported in both the bios and in Windows), but the system information from control panel displays the fact that only 32GB of this is usable.

I've only ever seen this with 32bit windows when there's too much RAM installed before.

It also seems unlikely that precisely half of the RAM is dodgy? Any ideas?

Many thanks

James
(warning: dev playing at server admin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely a licensing problem. As an example, the Standard Edition of Server 2003 64bit can use only 32GB of RAM, not for technical but licensing reasons.

What Edition do you run?

Comment: sorry, my own answer crossed yours! this was exactly it :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the guys who supplied the server installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition on it, which only supports up to 32GB of RAM

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx